# REGEX_EXTRACT in pig does not works

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

I want to remove double quotes '"' from begining and end of each field.
I'm trying to apply regexp in pig, but seems it doesn't work

**Input:**

```
(main_170521230001.csv,"9","2017-05-21 23:00:01.472636")
(main_170521230001.csv,"91","2017-05-21 23:00:01.472636")
(main_170521230001.csv,"592","2017-05-21 23:00:01.472636")
```

**Pig script:**

```
raw = LOAD '/data/csv' using PigStorage(',','-tagFile') as (
  fn:chararray,
  gid:chararray,
  createdts:chararray);

res = foreach raw generate
        REGEX_EXTRACT(fn, '([^"](.*)[^"])',1) as (fn:chararray),
        REGEX_EXTRACT(gid, '([^"](.*)[^"])',1) as (gid:chararray),
        REGEX_EXTRACT(createdts, '([^"](.*)[^"])',1) as (createdts:chararray);

dump res;
```

**Output:**

```
(ain_170521230001.cs,,017-05-21 23:00:01.47263)
(ain_170521230001.cs,91,017-05-21 23:00:01.47263)
(ain_170521230001.cs,592,017-05-21 23:00:01.47263)
```

**I expected:**

```
(main_170521230001.csv,9,2017-05-21 23:00:01.472636)
(main_170521230001.csv,91,2017-05-21 23:00:01.472636)
(main_170521230001.csv,592,2017-05-21 23:00:01.472636)
```

I want to receive all characters between "".
Examples:

```
"abc" -> abc
abc -> abc
""abc""" -> abc
"a"b"c" -> a"b"c
```

Thats why I'm using  this pattern:

```
'([^"](.*)[^"])'
```

It works fine, except one case - if there is a single character between double quotes this pattern returns empty string
why does it happen so?

Comment: Did you try using REPLACE?

Answer (score 0):

Load the data into a single field and use REPLACE.You can then use STRSPLIT to get the individual fields.

```
raw = LOAD '/data/csv' USING TextLoader();
res = foreach raw generate REPLACE($0,"\\"",'');
res_new = foreach res generate STRSPLIT($0,',',3);
dump res_new;
```